# Base64binary; xslt; java

Tags: xml base64 java xslt

Есть xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>SGVsbG8gd29yZA==</data>
```

Нужно вытряхнуть из data содержимое в строку, допустим так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<newData>Hello word</newData>
```

Пытаюсь делать это так:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="2.0" 
xmlns:b64dec="java:trash.MyBase64decoder"
exclude-result-prefixes="b64dec">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="d" select="data"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="b64dec:decode($d)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Где MyBase64decoder имеет такой вид:

```
package trash;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;

public class MyBase64decoder {

    public MyBase64decoder() {
    }

    public static String decode (String data) {
        return StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(data));
    }
}
```

Скомпилирован и лежит рядом с xml и xslt.

Запускаю все в Eclipse Kepler и разворачивает он меня с таким сообщением:

```
15:46:50,940 ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - The first argument to the non-static Java function 'decode' is not a valid object reference.
15:46:50,941 ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Could not compile stylesheet
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformerHandler(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.addStylesheet(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.addStylesheet(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.PipelineDefinition.addStyleSheet(PipelineDefinition.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.PipelineDefinition.configure(PipelineDefinition.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.Main.main(Main.java:72)
15:46:50,945 FATAL [main] Main  - Error with stylesheet: file:/C:/Users/evorobyev/workspace/asbc-unifo/testBase64Decode.xslt
org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.ConfigurationException: Error with stylesheet: file:/C:/Users/evorobyev/workspace/asbc-unifo/testBase64Decode.xslt
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.PipelineDefinition.addStyleSheet(PipelineDefinition.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.PipelineDefinition.configure(PipelineDefinition.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.Main.main(Main.java:72)
```

Я перепробовал еще кучу вариантов из различных примеров типа вот таких:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684909/xslt-convert-base64-data-into-image-files
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/HermannSW/entry/decoding_the_base64_dp_file_data_retrieved_by_xml_management_do_export_request17?lang=ru

Ругается аналогично... Никак не могу понять в чем дело.

Answer (score 2):

Как же я ненавижу XSLT - кто бы знал. XSLT это п**&%ец: кромешный адъ и трэш.

У вас походу неверно оформлен вызов Java функции, парсер воспринимает его как не статическую функцию и пытается узнать какой конкретно экземпляр нужно использовать, что он и сообщает через:

> The first argument to the non-static Java function 'decode' is not a valid object 
>   reference

То есть, в формате XSLT первый параметр вызова должен указывать на экземпляр класса откуда берется функция.

Почитайте [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136229/solvedxslt-call-java-instance-method) - как человек решал похожую задачу.

Comment: Да, про экземпляр класса я тоже понял. Я просто не понимаю почему он его требует для статического метода. Сейчас попробовал сделать метод не статическим и по аналогии с вашим примером. Говорит, что класс не найден, хотя он лежит под ногами. Пробовал и cp не могу понять в чем дело..

Answer (score 0):

Дело было во встроенном трансформаторе в эклипсе. Воспользовался отдельной библиотекой без всяких IDE и все завертелось как нужно.